# IPhone Memory management and CATransition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, catransition

Having some basic issues with managing the total  memory from adding and removeing a uiviewcontroller - but only when i add an animation to it using CAtransition. I set up a simple scenario below of the situation:

I have  a basic view controller that I init/alloc called IVC, and I  add to the current uiController:
IN the header file it is simply just declared:

```
IntroViewController* IVC;
```

AT START :3mb total memory shown in leaks

3.6mb total memory

```
IVC=[[IntroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Intro" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[IVC.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];   
[self.view addSubview:IVC.view];
```

then  i release:

```
[[IVC.view layer] removeAllAnimations];
[IVC.view removeFromSuperview];//remove intro animation
[IVC release];
```

as expected here total memory goes back to 3mb

but when i remove the release code and add the following so that there is a fade in and then release the object shown here:

```
CATransition *applicationIntroLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];
[applicationIntroLoadViewIn setDuration:.5];
[applicationIntroLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[applicationIntroLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[applicationIntroLoadViewIn setValue:@"IntroFadeIn" forKey:@"IntroAnimation"];
[applicationIntroLoadViewIn setDelegate:self];
[[IVC.view layer] addAnimation:applicationIntroLoadViewIn forKey:nil];
```

and then :

i create a method to handle when the animation has finished:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag{
NSString* value = [animation valueForKey:@"IntroAnimation"];

if ([value isEqualToString:@"IntroFadeIn"]){
    //this def gets called NSLog shows up
    [[IVC.view layer] removeAllAnimations];
    [IVC.view removeFromSuperview];//remove intro animation
    [IVC release];
    IVC=nil;
}
```

there are no reported leaks, the view is removed , but the memory still stays 3.6MB in Leaks?  ANy reason why this would happen? I don't alloc the animation* so i feel that should not need to be cleaned up, but this suggests that something is still holding onto to my IVC view

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try `applicationIntroLoadViewIn.removedOnCompletion = YES;` in your CATransition setup code snippet!

Comment: default value of removedOnCompletion is already to YES, this line of code is useless